# How to use OAuth client on GCP project #1 though another project #2 what is connected with firebase?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, identity-aware-proxy

The situation:
Project #1 : contains Load balancer and Identity Aware Proxy accessible though oauth client (android) on GCP project (credentials).
Project #2 : is a firebase project. GCP is configured automatically (just created project from firebase and at all). Here is added android applicatoin with sha1 and package name and authentication google is enabled.
**The question is:** How to configure android (flutter in my case) application via Firebase project #2 to get access to oauth web client on gcp project #1 to have access to iap ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest to start reading on the following [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start) which explains how to add Firebase Authentication to your application.

And also you can add IAP by using Firebase Cloud Functions which will act as a secured server which would help you with the process between the different projects.

I found [this](https://medium.com/@msasikanth/google-play-iap-verification-using-cloud-functions-bd8c3a22f9b9) article that explains a similar setup that you can do for your application.